# Controlling a latching solenoid with the DRV8838: Is this PCB design correct?

Tags: h-bridge, msp430, solenoid

I'm using the following Texas Instruments devices: [DRV8838](http://www.ti.com/product/DRV8838/datasheet) (Low-Voltage H-Bridge Driver) and [MSP430G2553](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430g2553.pdf) microcontroller. The purpose of the DRV8838 is to control a 9V latching solenoid. To test it, I have used the [the DRV8838 breakout board made by Pololu](https://www.pololu.com/product/2990). As I only need to have between OUT1 and OUT2 9V and -9V and sleep or turn on the DRV8838, the SLEEP and ENABLE pins are connected (see Table 2, page 11 on the datasheet).

I have developed a test code to open and close the solenoid and it works correctly. So far so good. The problem is that when designing my PCB, I made the mistake of not connecting pin 4 of the DRV8838 to GND so it did not work. I contacted the assembler who de-soldered the DRV8838 and connected pin 4 to GND through a wire. However I do not guarantee that everything is correct, because they had to do it by hand and the integrated circuit is very small.

The problem is that it still does not work (I use the same test code which I tested with the pololu breakout board). At this point, I don't know if my design is wrong, or if the re-soldering of the DRV8838 was not done correctly. So, I put the design of the circuit in case you see some design flaw that I'm not seeing.

In figure 1 is the schematic design of my PCB and in figure 2 is how I connected the development board of Pololu. Do you think there is a design error?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5bdsg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've attached a screenshot of the layout in case it helps to determine if the layout is correct or not. (R1 is a resistor that is not fitted because the DRV8838 already has internal pull-down resistors)

[image]

And this is a image with the 4th pin connected to GND through a wire:
[image]

If necessary I can upload the code. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: whats the supply on the MSP

Comment: also wondering why they had to desolder the chip to add a ground wire...

Comment: @Trevor the power supply of the msp430g2553 is the same as the logic power supply of the DRV8838 (3.6 V). Thank you.

Comment: Then it should work as far as I can see. Have you scoped it out to see what it is actually doing?

Comment: Is this your corrected artwork? Because we don't see a missing gnd under the chip , it is not clear.  but operating with out ground  *might* destroy the MSP with 9V pull-up. As usual, you need to probe the test points. ... which seem to be missing.

Comment: That's the problem, I do not have an oscilloscope. I measured with a digital multimeter the voltage on pin ENABLE, and PHASE SLEEP (through two vias that are in the image). Those values are correct. The measured voltage value between OUT1 and OUT2 is a few tens of millivolts

Comment: looks like it is sleeping

Comment: This is very robust and accepts input voltages within range if either or both supplies are off.  But it did not mention that also includes if  ground was missing. That may be fatal for the 8838 but I''m not sure.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yes, that is the already corrected PCB (pin 4 connected to GND).
when the ENANBLE and SLEEP pins are high, the IC is running. In addition, the same code works on the pololu breakout board so I think it's more of a HW problem.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 the DRV8838 was replaced by a new one, the problem is that it was soldered by hand with a wire in pin 4 to GND. Thanks Tony

Comment: yes if EN is high one of the Outputs must match Vm , whatever that read. Its that simple in logic.  !ext time be ESD and thermally aware not to exceed solder dwell time of a few seconds per pin. It should take less .

Comment: aDid U verify 0 ohms after on pin 4to gnd and no shorts. Imwould use AWG30 wire from pin 4 outside the existing IC since the path is only a few mm. then cut or use wood stick to hold short gnd wire and reflow both ends

Comment: "That's the problem, I do not have an oscilloscope" hmm... you cant tell much using a DMM, especially where there is software involved that may be messed up. Remove a variable, take out the CPU, or hold it in some state, and try injecting signals directly to the driver.

Comment: Trevor its simple nSleep and En are high, Phase only complements the signal. So the outpts must be active and complementary low RdsOn.  One only needs an Ohmeter to check for continuity and voltage on each pin then determine if ESd caused a failure or battery is no good or replace IC again more carefully.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 thanks Tony. Sorry, I'm a newbie in electronic design and some concepts I do not understand.
The voltage on the EN, SLEEP and PHASE pins are correct (high and low). The logic power level is correct (measured at C6) and the power level of the solenoid voltage (9V) is correct (measured at C5). However, the voltage between OUT1 and OUT2 is millivolts. I measured the continuity between the pins and seems to be fine :(
Do you think that apparently the design should work?

Comment: @Trevor Thanks Trevor. I have tested without the microcontroller by directly injecting a high level into the ENABLE-SLEEP and PHASE pins and the voltage between OUT1 and OUT2 is still millivolts.

Comment: OK so u know its not the micro... baby steps

Comment: @Trevor I'm starting to think that maybe the wire that connects pin 4 to GND is not fine. I'm going to edit and upload a photo in case it helps.

Comment: Perhaps but I'd think the outputs would be stuck high. THough they may actually just be high Z. You may want to test and see if they are actually being pulled low.

Comment: Excuse me Trevor, I did not quite understand what test you suggest me to do. Thank you.

Comment: if pin 4 is 0 ohms to gnd then measure output V D1 and D2 to gnd then use few hundred ohm R from D1 or D2  pullup to 9V to see if it is active or dead ( high Z out)  In any case N.G.

Comment: This started out as a design review question, which is just barely on-topic under the best of conditions, but has since devolved into a debug/repair question, which is definitely off-topic.

Comment: @DaveTweed Dave, I've been trying to keep this thread as a design question all the time, and not as a debug/repair issue which I understand would be off-topic, as you mention.
The point is that I'm not sure if the solution I'm porposing is failing due to a bad design, and that is exactly what I'm trying to find out from your responses.
So please, avoid any debugging aspects in my message and focus only on design concepts.
To be honest, I don't think this message has to be classified off-topic nor moved to another subforum. Thank you!!

Comment: Good design skills missing include: Layout, solder process control, thermal, design for test points and a good eye for details between your design and commercial solutions.  Debug skills missing are just continuity testing using Ohmeter to measure port impedance , back driving and basic function verification of any chip. This is just a single ended to differential tri-state switch with 2 inputs.

Comment: But that's the point -- you have neither the skills nor the equipment that would allow us to begin to help you. There would have to be a lot of back-and-forth just teaching you how to gather the information we would need, which is why such questions are not a good fit for this site. You have one design that works (the Pololu breakout board) and one that doesn't (your custom PCB) -- it's up to you to figure out what the *significant difference* is between them. It might include the fact that your board isn't properly assembled, or that a component has been damaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TVS diodes are useless here rated at 12V but operate up to 18V meanwhile only using a 9 V supply. The drivers have body diodes across Vds.

The driver is rated for 1.8A and 1.9A is the threshold for OCP.

### So if the solenoid resistance is less than 9V/1.8A = 0.5 ohm , the driver will go to sleep.

With a leadless chip that has a coplanarity of 0.02mm , I would have a hard time verifying a solder path exists even with a 10x magnifier.

My final thoughts are that manual soldering this chip cannot be easily used without skill and any rework must be done under a microscope.

Next time increase your pad size for probing and you are better of using a 3rd party driver board than DIY soldering these.

Until you get up to speed on layout quality and solder quality , I think for 4 bucks, you are better off buying this chip on a board.

See any difference?  See any gaps? or solder bridges, heatsink pad underneath soldered?

[image]

Catch my drift?

Comment: Thank you very much Tony for your patience and trying to help someone with my scant knowledge of electronics.
I will try to make a layout as close to the breakout board.
As for the solenoid resistance is over 6.5 ohms so the consumption never exceeds 1.5 A. Thank you for that warning.
As for the diodes, you think they are not necessary because they already have the transistors between drain and the source or because the value of the breakdown voltage is very high? Would you put 10v breakdown voltage TVS diodes? Thanks again.

Comment: There is always a period of time, called dead time, in which no FET is enabled. This small period of time, about 500 ns, is put in place to ensure no shoot through is generated. Shoot through (the enablement of both high and low side FETs on a per leg basis) would cause a short from supply (VM) to GND.
During this dead time, the opposing FET body diode will conduct. This is the asynchronous portion of the current decay.  Hence TVS is useless.